# recycle bitmap ice cream sandwich force close

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, recycle

In my ondestroy method, I recycle all the bitmaps I've used to free up memory and keep the app from crashing during screen rotations. This has proven to be the right thing to do for all apis until ice cream sandwich (android 4.0). now, when I rotate on ICS I get a force close and the logcat is not useful. I cannot trace it back to my code, but when I remove the bitmap recycling, it works great for ICS. Any ideas on this?

Comment: This might be unrelated, but recently I saw that the *initial* memory usage went up in ICS. I believe it's now prefetching all of the drawables. Perhaps even if you don't have a reference to the drawable, the framework still does and it's trying to set the bitmap that you recycled?

Comment: Can you tell if the crash is happening during onDestroy() or later? If you stick a Log.d(TAG, "message") call in a couple of places that might help discover? If it's during the actual recycle () call, what happens if you only call recycle() on Bitmap objects where isRecycled() returns false?

Answer (score 2):

Are you recycling bitmaps that were retrieved from the resources? It sounds like the OS keeps a reference to the Bitmap and uses it for future calls to the same resource. In that case, when the screen rotates, it will try to use the same Bitmap that you just recycled. This will result in a force close.

You may not need to recycle the bitmaps manually at all. It is a very dangerous call, especially on Bitmaps loaded from the resources.

Comment: Yes, I'm recycling the bitmaps that came from the resources. I'm ok with not calling recycle but that is the only way I've found to prevent OutOfMemoryErrors on non-ICS versions. Do you have any suggestions? I need this to work on Froyo and higher....

Comment: On our app, we download and cache a lot of images. We never know for sure if one is still being used, so we call System.gc() every once in a while. You could potentially call System.gc() where you were previously calling recycle(). On a side note, we also surround OutOfMemoryErrors in a try/catch and retry after a System.gc().

Comment: As I understand it, System.gc() doesn't help with the bitmap memory leakage in pre-ICS code. If things have silently changed between versions from "if you don't recycle bitmaps your image-intensive app will die" to "if you *do* recycle bitmaps your image-intensive app will die" then I am a most unimpressed developer.

Comment: I've had quite a lot of problems with Bitmap recycling. I don't know about the system holding resources over a config change but I DO know that 1 if a Bitmap has been put into an ImageView with setImageBitmap (Bitmap) you have to setImageBitmap(null) to free the memory, even if you've called recycle() and 2 if you have resources set in a View and you null them to free memory for a second Activity, the memory only gets freed if you do this in onPause()--onStop() is too late. The system does hold on to Bitmap data pretty tenaciously, even through recycle() calls.

Comment: +1 for not recycle bitmaps decoded from resources. I have a complex Volley-like system of tracking bitmaps from urls and recycling when their usage is 0, but just extended for resources and crashcrashcrashcrash until not recycling those.